# 406 Not Acceptable with jQuery + Spring 5 Rest

Tags: jquery, json, spring, rest, model-view-controller

I'm using Spring 5 MVC to respond with JSON to a request don with jQuery.

The client code is this:

```
    $.ajax({
         url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/spring.MVC.REST.simple-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Products.htm',
         dataType: 'json',
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(result){
             $('#resultados').html(result);
         }
     })
```

The request header is the expected, like this:

```
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
    Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/spring.MVC.REST.simple-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

So I think the issue is on the server side. I use WildFly 14 and the response header is like this:

```
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 73
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    Date: Fri, 19 Oct 2018 14:09:40 GMT
```

I was trying to send from server a  Content-Type: application/json but the client receive Content-Type: text/html (which is not accepted).

In the server I have a Controller. Here I put a snippet of the code:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/Products.htm")
    public class ProductsController {
        @Autowired
        private ProductManager productManager;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, 
           produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
           MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
        @ResponseBody
        public List<Product> getProducts() {
            return productManager.getProducts();
       }
     ....
```

Also I have in the WebConfig class a bean to negotiate the content between interactions http. Here there is a snippet code:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan("es.foxinet.springapp.web")
    public class SpringappWebConfig {
        @Bean
       public ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean 
              contentNegotiationManager() {
            ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean negociatorBean = new 
                ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
             negociatorBean.setFavorPathExtension(false);
             negociatorBean.setParameterName("mediaType");
             negociatorBean.setFavorParameter(true);
             negociatorBean.setIgnoreAcceptHeader(true);
             negociatorBean.setUseRegisteredExtensionsOnly(true);
           negociatorBean.setDefaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
           negociatorBean.addMediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
           negociatorBean.addMediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
           return negociatorBean;
       }
       .....
      }
```

Also I have in my Maven pon.xml file the next dependences to work with jackson (for json) and JAXB (for xml).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

What am I doing bad?

I'd appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's totally confusing how you make your endpoint url have an .htm extension, but it returns JSON (or XML), not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue. The point was in the content negociation I was doing wrong. The solution is in the  public class SpringappWebConfig (class for the web configuration). The class changes and gets like that:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   @ComponentScan("es.foxinet.springapp.web")
   public class SpringappWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
              configurer.favorPathExtension(false)
                 .parameterName("mediaType")
                 .favorParameter(true)
                 .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                 .useRegisteredExtensionsOnly(true)
                 .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
         }
       ....
      }
```

Although I fixed the issue by my self, I think it's important keep the post here because I've seen several posts with similar problems.